# Migration on Realm 0.81.1

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-migration

Got different exception after adding objects.

- migration needed
- class not found in scheme
- version on disk is newer than requested

What is wrong?

**1** - **MainActivity.java**

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration =
            new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            RealmTestObjectOne testObjectOne = new RealmTestObjectOne();
            testObjectOne.setValue(value);
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(testObjectOne);
        }
    });
```

**2** - **RealmTestObjectOne.java**

```
public class RealmTestObjectOne extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int key = 1;

    private String value;

    public RealmTestObjectOne() {
   }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**3** - **Build & run**

**4** - **Add RealmTestObjectTwo.java** 
Same as RealmTestObjectOne.java but different id

**5** - **Modify RealmConfiguration**

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration =
    new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
    .schemaVersion(2)
    .migration(new Migration())
    .build();
```

**5** - **Add Migration.java**

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public long execute(Realm realm, long l) {
        l += 1;
        return l;
    }
}
```

**SOLVED**

Thanks to @geisshirt answer.

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
@Override
public long execute(Realm realm, long version) {
    if (version == 0) {
        Table table = realm.getTable(RealmTestObjectTwo.class);
        table.addColumn(ColumnType.INTEGER, "key");
        table.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "value");
        table.setPrimaryKey("key");
        version += 1;
    }

    return version;
}
}
```

Comment: You Migration class does not tell to add the new RealmTestObjectTwo class and its fields to the schema. You can take a look here for an example: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java

Comment: Thanks. I saw that example already. It doesn't help because there are no interface to add new tables. It should be done automatically as I get it.

Comment: The method `Realm.getTable()` will create the table if does not exist.